# How to call a java class method from spring boot service layer

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have my Spring boot application from where I am trying to call a method from a java class in a different module outside of my application. I have the dependency added to my project pom for that external module. The external module is not Spring boot application. I have my code as below

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl {
    private MyInterface myInterface;
    
    public Response callMethod1() {
        Response response = new Response();
        response = myInterface.callMethod1();
        return response;
    }
}
```

Interface MyInterface and its implementation are part of the external module. Code is something like this.

```
public interface MyInterface {
    Response callMethod1();
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class InterfaceImpl implements MyInterface {
    Response callMethod1() {
        Response response = doSomething();
        return response;
    }
}
```

When I call the service method, I see it failing with InvocationTargetException. I tried the debugger in eclipse and I won't see the break points in the Implementation getting hit. I tried by moving the code of Interface and Implementation into my project with some modifications to see if I can make it work. Here are my changes.

Service Class:

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl {
    @Autowired
    private MyInterface myInterface;
    
    public Response callMethod1() {
        Response response = new Response();
        response = myInterface.callMethod1();
        return response;
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    Response callMethod1();
}
```

Implementation:

```
@Service
public class InterfaceImpl implements MyInterface {
    Response callMethod1() {
        Response response = doSomething();
        return response;
    }
}
```

How can I call the java class methods without changing the implementation and keeping it in its original module.

Thanks.

Comment: *I tried by moving the...* Did it work?

Comment: Yes, it did work if I move the code into my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    
    @Bean
    public Foo createFoo() {
        Foo foo = new Foo();    // this is POJO
        return foo; // after return it will be saved in Spring Context and become a Bean 
    } 

}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Here is the link with example that I found


https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-core/spring-configuration-annotation/